# Nextjs - render component inside async function

Tags: asynchronous, next.js

I'm new to Nextjs and I'm trying to map over a set of items in an array and pass them into a card component. But the Card component won't render on the page. If put the  between the div tags it will render.

```
const Results = () => {
getProductInformation().then( (a) => 
{
  let b = Object.keys(a).map((item) => {
    //console.log(a[item].ProductName);
      <Card/>
 }
})

return (
    <div class="resultView">
      {
     
        console.log(aitem.ProductName)
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Results;
```

I also wanted to pass a[item] to the card component as a prop and console.log it in the card Component, but when I try to console.log it from within the card component it returns: undefined.

Answer (score 0):

- `getProductInformation` might not be returning anything. I suggest you to `console.log(a)` here

  ```
  // make sure your promise resolving "a" or "a" is not empty array
  getProductInformation().then( (a) => console.log(a))
  ```
- you have to return `<Card/>` component

  ```
  getProductInformation().then( (a) => 
  {
    // you dont need `let b=`
     Object.keys(a).map((item) => {
      //console.log(a[item].ProductName);
      return <Card/>
  }
  })
  // after this scope of `a` is gone. you cannot access it after closing the parantheses
  ```

after this function call is complete, you cannot access `a` variable any more. its scope ended when

- you render inside `div` because you are actually returning something

Comment: getProductInformation() does return a set of objects - if I uncomment the console.log function it does return this.

Comment: I tried this also, but still nothing renders:

 ` getProductInformation().then( (a) => 
  {
    //console.log(a);
   Object.keys(a).map((item) => {
      //console.log(a[item].ProductName);
      return <Card item={a[item].ProductName}/> 
    })
  })`